# How to invert result using grep?

Tags: bash, grep

How to use grep

The string
"[TEST-4902]: This is a long placeholder string"

command

```
gh pr view 1  --repo joe/test-gh-cli --json body --jq .body | grep -v "TEST-[0-9]{3,4}"
```

Result

```
[TEST-4902]: This is a long placeholder string
```

how to return only "This is a long placeholder string"

expected output

```
This is a long placeholder string
```

Comment: You are using `grep -v` option which means it should ignore this line, but from your post I understood you want to print it. Could you please confirm on this one once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : We don't know which `grep` implementation the OP is using (Gnu, BSD,..). Note that `-E` is not specified. Therefore, `{3,4}` is taken as literal match unless this _grep_ takes extended regexp as default, and this would then explain the output under `-v`.

Comment: @user1934428, yeah I am aware of that about `-E` option but still thought to give a check on this one. Since OP accepted the answer so we know now what is OP's grep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using extended functionality `ERE` in a `BRE` `grep` so there is no match hence, your original line is returned.

If the `-E` flag is added in conjunction with your `-v` flag, then nothing will be printed as the match is now made so the line is ignored (not the part that is matched).

Using `grep` with `perl` style regex will do what you are looking for;

```
$ grep -Po 'TEST-[0-9]{3,4}]: \K.*' input_file
This is a long placeholder string
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view, the `--jq` option for that `gh pr view` command accepts a `jq` expression (see `man jq` or https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). A non-`grep` solution may be to build on your `--jq .body`, using `sub()` for example:

```
gh ...  --jq '.body | sub("^\\[TEST-\\d{3,4}\\]:\\s*"; "")'
```