# How to do you invert search using grep perl?

Tags: bash, grep

I've been trying to get this but i don't know how, I have been searching the internet but i cannot seem to find the solution for this, Any help would be appreciated,

My reference
[How to invert result using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216038/how-to-invert-result-using-grep)

```
gh pr view 6095 --repo freshGrad/main --json body | jq -r .body > temp.txt

#check file is not empty
if [ -s temp.txt ]; then
        # The file is not-empty.
        DESCRIPTION=$(grep -Po 'JCC-[0-9]{3,4}:\K.*' temp.txt) || echo "Something went wrong"
        echo "$DESCRIPTION"
        rm -f temp.txt
else
        # The file is empty.
        DESCRIPTION="No Description Provided"
        echo "$DESCRIPTION"
        rm -f temp.txt
fi
```

test number 1 JCC is not hyperlink
PR body string

```
JCC-452:Fix ServiceDate-OrderItem to correct drawdown order value calculation
```

output is good

```
Fix ServiceDate-OrderItem to correct drawdown order value calculation
```

test number 2 with hyperlink
Pr body string

```
[JCC-365]: Add new Variation Codes on Quote

[JCC-365]: https://myplace.atlassian.net/browse/JCC-365?atlOrigin=eyJpIjoi3NTljNzY6NjVmND23DlhMDU42fshYzA5YTRkg1LCJwIjoiZ2l0aHViLWNvbS1KU1cifQ
```

Output

```
Something went wrong
```

Expected Output

```
Add new Variation Codes on Quote
```

Comment: Your given regex will not match the square brackets in your 2nd example; maybe you can improve it with something like this `JCC-[0-9]{3,4}.*:\K.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you `grep` to this:

```bash
grep -m1 -Po 'JCC-\d{3,4}]?:\h*\K.*' temp.txt
```

In your script:

```bash
DESCRIPTION=$(grep -m1 -Po 'JCC-\d{3,4}]?:\h*\K.*' temp.txt) ||
echo "Something went wrong"
```

Note that `JCC` string has optional `]` afterwards and you also need to use `-m1` to grab only first match. `\h*` is also good to use to disallow leading spaces in output.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it works, cheers

Answer (score 0):

The pattern search is looking for JCC-nnn:, the second file has the JCC-nnn wrapped in '[' and ']' - the pattern fail looking for the ':' after the digit. To support both format, add ? in the pattern, to allow for option ']' before the ':'

```
grep -Po 'JCC-[0-9]{3,4}]?:\K.*' ...
```